# The difference between neutron and proton separation energy of a nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, protons, binding-energy, strong-force

For a given nucleus, why does the value of the neutron separation energy $S_n$ differ from the value of the proton separation energy $S_p$? One of the reasons that is immediately obvious is that the neutrons being electrically neutral, are expected to be less tightly bound than protons. This suggests that the $S_p$ must be somewhat smaller than $S_n$. Is this true? If not, why?

Comment: At the neutron drip line, the neutron separation energy is zero.

Comment: @rob you haven't taken into account the residual strong force.

Comment: @Cerise I'm not sure what you mean in this context. If you keep adding neutrons to a nucleus, releasing the "separation energy" of the daughter as it de-excites to its ground state, eventually you get a nucleus where energy must be *added* to bind another neutron. Such a nucleus will have a neutron fall off in a very brief time. This is the "neutron drip line," where the neutron separation energy (zero or negative) is manifestly less than the proton separation energy.

Answer (score 2):

Here are plots of proton and neutron separation energies for a number of isotopes, from the [National Nuclear Data Center](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat3/):

> Neutron separation energy:
> [image: neutron separation energy versus neutron number]

The curve for calcium $(Z=20)$ is highlighted, and there are data from the proton [drip line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_drip_line) at calcium-34-ish to the neutron drip line at calcium-61-ish.  You can see that the neutron-deficient isotopes on the left *really want to keep their neutrons*, costing as much as 24 MeV to liberate one. By contrast, at the neutron drip line, the neutron separation energy is *zero*. That's why the heavy end of the line of isotopes is called the "drip line": it costs *nothing* to separate the neutron, so the neutron just falls off of the nucleus.

The neutron separation energy of exactly zero for calcium-61 seems to be an assumption rather than a measurement. However, in the lower left of the figure, you can see some less-massive elements whose drip-line isotopes actually have *negative* neutron separation energy. Those neutrons not only fall off, but liberate a couple mega-eV of energy when they do so.

The jagged shape of the neutron curve comes from the nuclear pairing interaction. An even-odd nucleus, like calcium-27, is generally less stable than nearby even-even nuclei, like calcium-28.  It costs less energy to liberate an unpaired neutron from calcium-27 than to liberate a paired neutron from either calcium-26 or -28.

> Proton separation energy:
> [image: proton separation energy versus neutron number]

Here we have the proton separation energies, with the calcium $(Z=20)$ curve highlighted again.  We don't see the pairing effect, because this is the energy required to knock a proton off and go down to potassium, so we are always unmaking a proton pair.  In the proton case, the dripline separation energy at calcium-33 actually *is* negative, while the nucleus holds on to its protons more and more tightly as we approach the proton-deficient neutron drip line on the right.

> Level diagrams for doubly-magic calcium isotopes:
> [image: level diagrams for calcium-40 and -48]

To give you an idea of what's happening microscopically, here are some schematic shell-model level diagrams for the two doubly-magic isotopes of calcium, Ca-40 and Ca-48.  In the [nuclear shell model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model), nucleons within a nucleus occupy orbitals with particular energies. This is very closely related to the more familiar [electron shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell) whose properties give shape to the periodic table. In particular, at some electron/proton/neutron numbers, you encounter a "full shell" with a large energy gap before the next available orbital; such "full shells" are particularly stable. Atoms with a full electron shell are the noble gases; the full neutron and proton shells, which occur at different particle numbers, are said to have a "magic number" of nucleons.  In the diagram, you can see the gaps at two, eight, twenty, and twenty-eight nucleons.

Notice that the proton energy levels are further apart than the neutron energy levels, thanks to electrical repulsion among the protons. If you construct a nucleus with a full neutron level at a higher energy than a vacant proton orbital, that nucleus can reduce its internal energy via beta decay. This diagram suggests that both of these isotopes are beta-stable, which is approximately true.

In order to separate a nucleon, you have to kick it up to the continuum. The separation energy is the energy gap between the least-tightly-bound nucleon and the continuum. (Compare to ionization energy for electron shells.) To go from calcium-48 to calcium-40, you'd remove the top eight neutrons, requiring (from the first figure) about eight or twelve mega-eV for each neutron.
As you do this, the nucleus becomes more proton-rich, and the proton separation energy decreases.

For a given nucleus, the proton and neutron separation energies will nearly *always* be different. However, which separation energy is larger will depend on the internal structure of the nucleus.